# Multiple long tables per page

Tags: longtable

I have table with a large number of lines but only a small width.

Is it possible to create a longtable which creates a second (or third) table next to the first before going over to the next page and does the same on the following pages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Comment: no, not using longtable (or not easily) but often such things can be set as a list rather than a table, then you could use the multicol package to wrap the list to (say) 3 columns.